# Is there any biblical reference to a third temple being built?

Tags: bible, history

In referrence to to end times; does the Bible say anywhere that a third temple will be built?

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site. Unfortunately we don't allow verse search questions here. But I'm sure you'll be able to search elsewhere to find the verses that talk about this.

Comment: @curiousdannii I notice there is no longer a 'close-vote' category for verse seaches.

Comment: @NigelJ There never was, only on BH.SE

Comment: From which eschatological and/or denominational viewpoint? In some forms of pre-millennial dispensationalism, for example, various passages are used to support it. In other views, passages are used to say it either a) already happened, or b) isn't going to happen, or c) doesn't matter one way or the other

Comment: @curiousdannii - this isn't a "verse search question", from what I can see